# jQuery form submit download does't work in ipad safari

Tags: c#, jquery, ios, asp.net-mvc, safari

I have a chart and I need to take a screenshot of that chart. Taking screenshot is working fine in FF, Chrome, IE and Safari desktop PC and even in android devices. But not working in ipad mini Safari.

Here is my server(C#) side code

```
public ActionResult DownloadChartImage(string base64Data, string chartType)
{
    byte[] fileInfo = null;

    fileInfo = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);

    return File(fileInfo, "application/octet", chartType + "_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".png");
}
```

My client side code

```
function DownloadChart(canvas) {

    var postURL = $("#hdnSiteURL").val() + "/Report/DownloadChartImage";

    $("#frmDownloadChart").attr("action", postURL);
    $("#base64Data").val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("data:image /png;base64,", ""));
    $("#frmDownloadChart").submit();
    $("#base64Data").val("");
}

$("#btnLineDownload").click(function () {
    $("#divLineCompanyInfo").show();
     $('#divPanelBodyLine').html2canvas({
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        $("#chartType").val("Line");
        DownloadChart(canvas);            
        $("#divLineCompanyInfo").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML lines

```
<form id="frmDownloadChart" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="base64Data" name="base64Data" />
  <input type="hidden" id="chartType" name="chartType" />
</form>
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.